# Hibernate session.get returns null

Tags: hibernate

Here is my full class which has got two methods one for insert and other for update. Insert method inserted successfully and I can see the record in the table but while fetching in update method returning null in spite of data record present in the table.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MyApplicationDAOImpl implements MyApplicationDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // Insert Method            
    public boolean insertUpdateMyData(Long Key,String message)throws Exception {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        MyData data = new MyData();
        data.setKey(Key);
        data.setMessage(message);
        session.saveOrUpdate(data);
        return true;
    }

    //This is update method     
    @Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean updateMyData(Long Key,
            String new_message)throws Exception {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        MyData data = (MyData) session.get(MyData.class,Key,LockMode.UPGRADE);
        if(data != null)
        {
            data.setMessage(new_message);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(data);
            session.flush();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            session.flush();
            return false;
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: Not the same key? No transaction ensuring that the save is committed? Post a complete test case.

Comment: who is Key (capitalized) ??

Comment: I have posted complete test case.

Comment: Agree with @JBNizet. Two things I notice - first, transaction is not being started and committed in insertUpdateSMLintoMyData(...). Unless you are managing transactions using Spring or other container, you need to start transaction - session.beginTransaction() and commit it - session.getTransaction().commit(). Second, do close the session after using it.

Comment: I am using the spring annotation for transaction which is working for all other methods. Do I have to add session.flush() after session.saveOrUpdate(data); in insert method?

Comment: The `session.get()` method will only return null if a object is nonexistent with a given key. Try debugging and check the database if your entity was really created there after the `insertUpdateMyData()` method.

Comment: I have cross checked entity was created successfully and I can run the query on database with the key. My doubt is in insertUpdateMyData method I am not using session.flush() to persist the data in to table to fetch by another method. I am not sure this is correct or not.

Comment: Excellent !! I did the same and worked. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Given there is no @Transactional on insertUpdateMyData I'll just assume you have some top level method like...

```
@Transactional
public void upperLevelMethod() {
    Key key = getKeyFromSomewhere();
    String message = getMessageFromSomewhere();
    insertUpdateMyData(key, message);
    String newMessage = getNewMessageFromSomewhere();
    updateMyData(key, newMessage);
}
```

The `upperLevelMethod` will create a transaction (transaction A) which `insertUpdateMyData` will inherit and then `updateMyData` will create a brand new transaction (since you have requires_new, we'll call it transaction B).  Since transaction A isn't committed at the time transaction B starts and transaction B has serialization level isolation that means that transaction B will not see any changes made by transaction A.

You will either need to commit the transaction used by `insertUpdateMyData` before calling `updateMyData` or change `updateMyData` to inherit the same transaction.

Comment: Excellent !! I did the same and worked. Thanks you very much